# three character search not working

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search, character-limit

I am using `FullText` Searching in `MySQL` my database table engine type is `MyISAM`.

Now problem is that i want to allow use to search record if they have entered three words.

But problem is that `FullText` not allowing me to search record less than 4 character.

> **I know i can change `ft_min_word_len` to make it work but when i will upload it i need to change it on server and i am using shared host so its hard.**

So how can i make it work in mysql Query.

I think when word are less than 4 character use `LIKE` clause and when its greter than 4 use `fulltext`, Is this right way?

**Code**

```
App::import('Sanitize');

if(strlen($this->params['named']['q']) <= 4)
{
    $lessWord = "+".$this->params['named']['q'];
}
else
{
    $lessWord = $this->params['named']['q'];
}

$escapedQuery = str_replace(" ","* ",Sanitize::escape($lessWord)).'*';

array_push($this->paginate['conditions'],"MATCH(ServiceRequest.title, ServiceRequest.description) AGAINST ('".$escapedQuery."' IN BOOLEAN MODE)");

$this->paginate['fields'] = array
(
    '*',
    "MATCH(ServiceRequest.title, ServiceRequest.description) AGAINST ('".$escapedQuery."' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS score"
);
$this->paginate['order'] = "score DESC";
```

I have used above code.

is it possible to search three character ?

I also tried `+str*` but still now working.

Comment: @Jocelyn as i said i do not want to change that variable...please do not close it before read it....

Comment: @Jocelyn i have highlighted response to your close vote in question

Comment: @DipeshParmar +1 for nice question, waiting for right answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ft_min_word is a setting of the MySQL server. In case of hosting server, you cannot therefore change it in the ini_set (which isfor PHP).
The server is a seperate thing, and if your host has multiple users using the same server (which is standard on a shared server), they will use the same setting.

The same goes for a .htaccess setting: this can only change how apache will react (if allowed to change), not how the database server is configured.

The variable, described [here in the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_ft_min_word_len) is not a [dynamic variable](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/dynamic-system-variables.html) that can be set in runtime

So you  can try :

Check the length of the search term, then, if it is less than allowed by ft_min_word, use LIKE('%searchterm%')

Answer (score 0):

change this line

```
if(strlen($this->params['named']['q']) <= 3)
```

Comment: Thanx for reply but thats not gonna help...but thanx for reply.

Comment: Have you tried? anyway change and look that I hope that should be the prob